# Instagram - Obtaining data in realtime

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to get the recent post from a particular location. using this url.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=34.0500&lng=-118.2500&distance=50&MAX_ID=max_id&access_token=XXXX
```

So when I use this URL for the first time, I get 20 results. I obtain the max ID from the list of 20 results and modify my url .

But when I use the modified URL, I obtain the same result as the first one.

How do I go about solving this?

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to what I thought, the media search endpoint doesn't return a pagination object. Sorry.  It also doesn't support the min_id/max_id parameters, which is why you are having problems..

If you want to get different data you are going to have to use the time based request parameter MIN_TIMESTAMP. However it looks like that parameter doesn't work for that endpoint either (though the documentation says it is supported). Indeed, a quick search on the internet reveals it might be a long standing bug with the api.

Comment: hey thanks for the response. Now if I use this link - https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=34.0500&lng=-118.2500&distance=1050&access_token=XXXX , in the json response i do not get the next_max_id or the next url. @Robert